# Existence of an asymptote for $g(x)=\frac{f(x)f'(x)+f(1)f'(1)}{f'(x)+f'(1)}-f\left(\frac{xf'(x)+f'(1)}{f'(x)+f'(1)}\right)$

Tags: derivatives, asymptotics, convex-analysis, examples-counterexamples, jensen-inequality

Working with the Slater's inequality (companion of Jensen's inequality) I find this statement :

> > Let $f(x)$ be a continuous,$n$ times differentiable ,convex and non constant on $(0,\infty)$ and increasing on $(1,\infty)$ and finally with  non bounded derivatives then define :
> > $$g(x)=\frac{f(x)f'(x)+f(1)f'(1)}{f'(x)+f'(1)}-f\left(\frac{xf'(x)+f'(1)}{f'(x)+f'(1)}\right)$$
> > With $g(x)$ strictly increasing on $(1,\infty)$.

> > Claim: $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{g(x)}{x}=constant$

I have not the key to approach the general case but let me try some example :

For my first example I take the exponential [see here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20%20&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22Limit%22%2C%20%22limit%22%7D%20-%3E%22infinity%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22Limit%22%2C%20%22limitfunction%22%7D%20-%3E%222%20%28e%5E%282%20x%29%2Be%5E%282%29%29%2F%28e%5E%28x%29%2Be%5E%281%29%29-2%20e%5E%28%28x%20e%5E%28x%29%2Be%5E%281%29%29%2F%28e%5E%28x%29%2Be%5E%281%29%29%29%2B4e-2*e*x%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C%20%22limit%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%22Calculator%22%7D) .The function can be decreasing or increasing on a such interval see as example the function $f(x)=x^x$.As particular case we have $f(x)=x+\frac{1}{x}$  this asymptote is constant.So in fact I have tried only elementary function and their compositions but it would be curious that it works only for them.

My question :

Have you counter-example (it would be perfect because I have some doubt on this statement) or a proof (which I think is not easy) ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Have you tried $x^2-2x$?

Comment: @Alexander51413 I find as asymptote $y=0$ no ?

Comment: Sorry I interpreted the word asymptote incorrectly. If you don't want $g(x)$ to tend to a straight line, $\sin(x)+x^2/2$ looks like it works

Comment: @Alexander51413 yes it seems to work !

Comment: @Alexander51413 Thanks !! I have edited the question see now and tell me if i'm wrong !

Comment: @AlexRavsky Any suggestions ?

Comment: $g'(1)$ is always $0$, so to find a counter-example would require $g'(x)$ to have a minimum at $(1, 0)$, which is quite restrictive. I haven't found any, but if counter-examples exists they're going to be hard to find.

Comment: @Alexander51413 maybe we can build a such counter-example .

Comment: @Alexander51413 have you a reference for this problem ?

Comment: @ErikSatie By "have an asymptote", do you mean $\lim_{x\to \infty} (g(x) - ax - b) = 0$ for some constants $a, b$? If so,  try $f(x) = x^{3/2}$?

Comment: @RiverLi Nice counter-example , can you formulate an answer ?

Comment: @ErikSatie It is fine as a comment. Thanks.

Comment: @ErikSatie By the way, it appears that $\lim_{x\to \infty} \dfrac{g(x)}{x}$ exists?

Comment: @RiverLi I trust it so I change the question . Thanks !!

Comment: @ErikSatie If we apply L'Hopital's rule, $\lim_{x\to \infty} \dfrac{g(x)}{x} = \lim_{x\to \infty} g'(x)$, is it true that $\lim_{x\to \infty} g'(x)$ exists?

Comment: @RiverLi we need to show that , I have tried to apply strong convexity and Jensen's inequality but we get a lower bound instead of a upper bound !

Comment: @RiverLi I find a nice definition of a particular kind of convex function it's : " said to be convex with respect to F, or briefly F-convex" I quote and see : https://www.mdpi.com/2073-8994/12/1/13/htm   line (3) . Is it relevant ?

Comment: I don't know. I guess not.