# Conjecture regarding the function $f(x)=e^{x^n}$ and asymptotics behavior .

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, exponential-function

Hi it's a follow up of my false conjecture see [Existence of an asymptote for $g(x)=\frac{f(x)f'(x)+f(1)f'(1)}{f'(x)+f'(1)}-f\left(\frac{xf'(x)+f'(1)}{f'(x)+f'(1)}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3920773/existence-of-an-asymptote-for-gx-fracfxfxf1f1fxf1-f-le) .

It's a particular example wich seems to work :

Let $f(x)=e^{x^n}$ where $x\geq 0$ and $1\leq n$ a natural number then define :

$$g(x)=\frac{f(x)f'(x)+f(1)f'(1)}{f'(x)+f'(1)}-f\left(\frac{xf'(x)+f'(1)}{f'(x)+f'(1)}\right)$$

> > Claim: $g(x)$ have an asymptote as $x\to \infty$

Geogebra have some problem with big numbers so there is a big part of luck .

For the case $n=1$ I have tried Laurent's series and see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20%20&assumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22Limit%22,%20%22limit%22%7D%20-%3E%22infinity%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22Limit%22,%20%22limitfunction%22%7D%20-%3E%222%20%28e%5E%282%20x%29%2Be%5E%282%29%29/%28e%5E%28x%29%2Be%5E%281%29%29-2%20e%5E%28%28x%20e%5E%28x%29%2Be%5E%281%29%29/%28e%5E%28x%29%2Be%5E%281%29%29%29%2B4e-2*e*x%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22,%20%22limit%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%22Calculator%22%7D) .

My question :

Have you an counter-example or a proof if so ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got
\begin{align*}
g(x) & = \frac{{nx^n e^{x^n } e^{x^n }  + ne^2 }}{{nx^n e^{x^n }  + ne}} - \exp \left[ {\left( {\frac{{nx^{n + 1} e^{x^n }  + ne}}{{nx^n e^{x^n }  + ne}}} \right)^n } \right]
\\ &
 = e^{x^n }  + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{x^n e^{x^n } }}} \right) - \exp \left[ {x^n \left( {1 - \frac{{ne}}{{x^n e^{x^n } }} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{x^{n + 1} e^{x^n } }}} \right)} \right)} \right]
\\ &
 = e^{x^n }  + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{x^n e^{x^n } }}} \right) - e^{x^n }  + ne + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{x}} \right) = ne + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{x}} \right)
\end{align*}
as $x\to +\infty$. Thus, the line $x=ne$ is an asymptote of $g(x)$ as $x\to +\infty$.